# Macro to refer cell values from multiple Excel worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with 50 tabs (each tab named as a country. e.g Australia, Austria etc.). I need to create a summary sheet which lists out all the country names and add 2 values for each country that refers to 2 cells from each corresponding tab for that country (say E20, F20)

Given below are the images of the summary tab and a country tab. I manually referred the cell to summary tab. How can I do it for 50 tabs using formula/macro?

[image: tab]
[image: summary]

Comment: What have you done so far? Code please?

Comment: You could get the sheet names and numbers using a combination of `Indirect` and `Cell("filename")`. Yet, I wouldn't take that route as `Indirect` is a volatile function. So, I'd stay away from that one (as much as possible). Instead you should use VBA and something along the line of `For each sht in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`. Yet, this website does not offer free coding services. Hence, I suggest that you give it a try first and come back with your own very first VBA coding attempt in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ralph mentions you should do something along the lines of:

```
public sub example1()
    r=2
    sheets("Summary").Range("A1") = "SheetName"
    sheets("Summary").Range("B1") = "Sales"

    sheets("Summary").Range("C1") = "Profit"

    For each sh in thisworkbook.sheets
        'Sheet Name
        sheets("Summary").Range("A" & r) = sh.Name
        'Sales
        sheets("Summary").Range("B" & r) = sheets(sh.Name).range("A2")
        'Profit
        sheets("Summary").Range("C" & r) = sheets(sh.Name).range("B2")
        'Increment Row number 
        r=r+1
    Next sh
END SUB
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may try something like this...

```
Sub CreateSummary()
Dim sws As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sws = Sheets("Summary")
sws.UsedRange.Cells.Clear
With sws.Range("A1:C1")
    .Value = Array("Country", "Sales", "Profit")
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 14
End With
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If Not ws Is sws Then
        lr = sws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.Range("E20:F20").Copy sws.Range("B" & lr)
        sws.Range("A" & lr).Value = ws.Name

    End If
Next ws
sws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Borders.Color = vbBlack
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```